# Python XMLRPC is forcing strings with just numbers to integers whereas Perl does not

Tags: python, xml, perl

We have a perl XMLRPC server in our web service that other teams in our place query via python scripts using XMLRPC.

Here's the thing - one of the parameters that we return is an ID of say, an employee, and due to the setup of the employee ids at our institute the IDs are in a format like this:

`000126721` (basically every id for every employee is the same length, and start off with 0 or more 0's to enforce this).

In the perl server side, we force this to be a string - and perl returns a hashref to xmlrpc in a format like this to ensure that the **employee id is forced to be a string**:

`{employee_id => "$employee_id"}`

So in perl the above example is returned like this if we query our perl server with a perl client:

`{employee_id => "000126721"}`

But apparently the other teams are telling us that python xmlrpc when it grabs the ids *truncates the 0s and turns employee id to an integer* such that it gets the above field like this:

`{employee_id : 126721}`

??? Why on earth would xmlrpc in python force something that is explicitly specified as a string into an integer?

If I stick in say a comma in the id, python xmlrpc does not do this - but if any string that is getting returned consists purely of numbers, python xmlrpc client seems to convert it to  integer (and therefore the preceding zero's are lost when they MUST be kept) whereas perl does not seem to do this client or server side.

What can we do to solve this issue?  We tested this with a different rest web service using JSON, YAML, and none of the other ones seem to have this issue, just XMLRPC. Unfortunately, until our next release, we *will have to find a way to fix the XMLRPC* so... :(

EDIT: Here's another issue that I forgot to mention -- employee id is *not the only field that does this*. There are other fields that do the same thing but also enforce a different amount of digits. So ideally rather than modifying the data post-xmlrpc in python (that really wouldn't be hard to do but risks screwing up the data, and the data is actually sensitive data that cannot be and should not be touched), we would really need to find a way to force xmlrpc to not convert.

Comment: Maybe the Python client supports an xsd and you can provide that, saying that the columns are not only forced to be strings, but just defining them as strings.

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to find any references to xsd in python client library. :(    Do you have any other suggestions?